Spring redis OM unable to resolve
I have a spring 3.1 and java 21 gradle project and am trying to add this dependency
my repositories are defined in gradle as follows:
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
maven {
    url = uri("https://packages.confluent.io/maven/")
}


implementation("com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.9.6")

every time i build i get the following error
Could not resolve com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.9.6.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve group.springframework.ai:spring-ai-bom:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve group.springframework.ai:spring-ai-bom:1.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/group/springframework/ai/spring-ai-bom/1.1.0/spring-ai-bom-1.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/group/springframework/ai/spring-ai-bom/1.1.0/spring-ai-bom-1.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.9.6.


⚠️ Redis OM Spring versions greater than v0.9.1 require the addition of the Spring Milestone Repository to account for the recent integration with the Spring AI project. When Spring AI v1.0.0 is released we will drop this requirement.
<repository>
  <id>spring-milestones</id>
  <name>Spring Milestones</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
</repository>

More details in readme: https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring#official-releases
